# break inside for loop within while loop

Tags: java, do-while, break, conditional-breakpoint

I tried to break out of a  `for` loop but it doesn't break.

How do I get or break out of this `do...while` loop from inside of the `for` loop?

Here `CompanyEmployee` is an `ArrayList` of objects of the `Employee` class and the `CasualEmployee` class inherits from the `Employee` class.

```
do {
     System.out.print("ENTER ID:\t");
     String s=s3.nextLine();

            for(int i=3;i<9;i++) {
                System.out.println(CompanyEmployee.get(i).getID());
                    if(s==CompanyEmployee.get(i).getID()) {
                        String data=CompanyEmployee.get(i).toString();
                        WeekSchedule[check1][check]=data;
                        break;                  
                    }
            }
}
while(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a label to indicate which loop you want to break out of:

```
    loopLabel: do{

      ...
      for(int i=3;i<9;i++){

        if(...){
          ...
          break loopLabel;
        }
      }
    }
    while(true);
```